# JAVA_HOME gets mangled by Maven

Tags: maven-2, ant, maven

I'm retrofitting bunch of existing Java projects with unified Maven build. Since each project is mature and has established Ant based build all I'm using `maven-antrun-plugin` to execute existing `build.xml` as follows:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <ant antfile="build.xml" target="compile" />
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

When I run `mvn compile` build fails with this message:

```
[INFO] An Ant BuildException has occured: The following error occurred 
       while executing  this line:
build.xml:175: Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_13\jre"
```

What puzzles me is

1. I have `JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_13` as part of my environment setup and when `mvn.bat` is executed that is exactly value I'm getting, however as you see in the error message it comes up as `C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_13\jre`
2. If I run `ant compile` everything compiles just fine

Does it mean that perhaps `maven-antrun-plugin` does something like `set JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%\jre`? I searched my batch/build files I can't find where that change occurs

Answer (score 22):

Thats the down side of external links in an accepted answer. Codehaus shut down and thus the solution is gone. For reference here's the content behind the link - you basically only need to copy the `<dependencies>...</dependencies>` block to your antrun plugin...

*The maven-antrun-plugin runs ant with JAVA_HOME set to the **jre** subdirectory of the JDK, even if the JAVA_HOME for the overall run is a JDK.
 There is documentation elsewhere about how to create a dependency at the project level for the JDK's tools.jar, but this does not help out antrun, which is a plugin.
 The following profile does the job. The '..' in the path hauls up past the 'jre' directory to the lib directory.*

```
<profiles>
      <profile>
          <id>tools.jar</id>
          <build>
            <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
              <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
                  <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
                  <version>1.5.0</version>
                  <scope>system</scope>
                  <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
                </dependency>
              </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            </plugins>
          </build>
      </profile>
```

Comment: Thanks for expanding the broken link!

Comment: You sir, are the internet hero, thanks, i was searching for this for hours. It works. I just changed to java version 1.8.0.  

This should be the accepted answer now!

Comment: How do you resolve this in Java 9, as tools.jar has been removed?

Answer (score 21):

I was able to fix this by putting the following property definition in my ant build.xml file:

```
<property name="build.compiler" value="extJavac"/>
```